# How to disable prettier errors in reactjs project and also no-unsued-vars error

Tags: reactjs

I keep getting these errors when i am trying to run a reactjs project

```
prettier/prettier
  Line 23:39:  Replace `'react-toastify'` with `"react-toastify"`                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          prettier/prettier
  Line 29:59:  Delete `⏎`                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  prettier/prettier
```

And following is my `.eslintrc.js`

```
module.exports = {
  parser: "babel-eslint",
  env: {
    es6: true,
    node: true,
    browser: true,
  },
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 6,
    sourceType: "module",
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
  },
  plugins: ["react"],
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended",
  ]
};
```

and following is the package.json

```
{
  "name": "material-dashboard-react",
  "version": "1.10.0",
  "description": "Material Dashboard React. Coded by Creative Tim",
  "private": false,
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "4.11.4",
    "@material-ui/icons": "4.11.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "chartist": "0.10.1",
    "classnames": "2.3.1",
    "history": "5.0.0",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "1.5.1",
    "prop-types": "15.7.2",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-chartist": "0.14.4",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-swipeable-views": "0.14.0",
    "react-toastify": "^7.0.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "install:clean": "rm -rf node_modules/ && rm -rf package-lock.json && npm install && npm start",
    "lint:check": "eslint . --ext=js,jsx;  exit 0",
    "lint:fix": "eslint . --ext=js,jsx --fix;  exit 0",
    "build-package-css": "cp src/assets/css/material-dashboard-react.css dist/material-dashboard-react.css",
    "build-package": "npm run build-package-css && babel src --out-dir dist"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/creativetimofficial/material-dashboard-react.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Creative Tim <hello@creative-tim.com> (https://www.creative-tim.com/)",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/creativetimofficial/material-dashboard-react/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://creativetimofficial.github.io/material-dashboard-react/#/dashboard",
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.14.0",
    "typescript": "4.2.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "3.4.0",
    "gulp": "4.0.2",
    "gulp-append-prepend": "1.0.9",
    "prettier": "2.2.1"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": []
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you do not want it to completely stop you from running the web app, you can change the severity level of prettier from "error" to "warn".

in your `.eslint.json` file `rules` object, change from

```js
"prettier/prettier": "error",
```

to

```js
"prettier/prettier": "warn",
```

Comment: thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for in order to still build while addressing style issues later

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want `prettier` errors in your `eslint` output, just remove that

```
"plugin:prettier/recommended",
```

line in the Eslint configuration.

However, it would just be better to adhere to those suggestions -- depending on your IDE, you can just tell it to run `eslint --fix` for you, which'll fix that right up.

Comment: I am using sublime text. How to use eslint ---fix

Comment: If you look at your `package.json`, you'll see there's a `lint:fix` script configured. If you're using npm, `npm run lint:fix`. If you're using yarn, `yarn lint:fix`.